# perl one-liner like grep?

Tags: linux, perl, grep

i'd like perl to do a one-liner like `grep`

a bit like this, but i'm not sure what to add to make it work

```
$ (echo a ; echo b ; echo c) | perl -e 'a'
```

ADDED
My answer here covers that and more
https://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regex-in-terminal

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848360/how-can-i-implement-unix-grep-in-perl

Comment: Unless you're on some incredibly locked down Linux where `grep` isn't available, it's probably better to just use `grep` :-)

Comment: See also the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) manpage.

Comment: and if you just want to do grep but with Perl regular expressions, then use `ack` (by installing the `App::ack` distribution)

Comment: Just curious, what do you want to do that 'egrep' isn't enough?

Comment: @Harmen  grep could do it, but there is no option to search for new lines is there? I guess i'd have to use |tr and remove new lines.. which I suppose would make things not so readable if I wanted to see exactly what grep is going through. But perl has more powerful search facility, being able to find new lines.

Comment: @Harmen some things are perl-compatible only, and not really regular expressions, like negative look-behind assertions.

Comment: @Jayen what makes perl-compatible only, not really a regex?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question @barlop, but maybe this will help you: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
(echo a; echo b; echo c) | perl -ne 'print if /a/'
```

Comment: And if you need two conditions, try `| perl -ne 'print if /a/ || /b/'` or `| perl -ne 'print if /(a|b)/'`. On a 5gb csv, the capturing group was about 10% faster. On normal size data the difference was imperceptible. I find the `||` "or" style a bit more readable.

Answer (score 5):

To echo mob's comment:

If you want to use Perl regexes try `ack`: http://betterthangrep.com/

Comment: ack is perl, but wrapped up all nice an pretty

Comment: @barlop It's the difference between `ack '^\S+foo\s'` and `perl -wlne 'm{^\S+foo\s} and print'` — so about ~20 characters saved every time I use ack instead of perl for this purpose. Also when Perl shows the results it does not use any colors whereas ack colorizes output similar to grep.

Comment: @NoahSussman interesting.. Two issues I have with sed's "s..." i.e. sed for replacement is that it's line by line and has no binary mode.  I guess ack doesn't have those limitations? Also, can ack beat  sed's ability to print the nth line  `(echo a & echo b) | sed -n  "2p"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with Ruby, if you can afford other options

```
$ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | ruby -ne 'print if /a/'
a
$ (echo a; echo b; echo c) | ruby -ne 'print if $_["a"]'
a
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was looking for something for shell one-liners - Python is way too clunky, even Py2. Good to know, that Ruby takes after its daddy Perl here.