# Curl wildcard delete

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to use curl to delete files before i upload a new set, I'm having trouble trying to wildcard the files.

The below code works to delete one specific file

```
curl -v -u usr:"pass" ftp://11.11.11.11/outgoing/ -Q "DELE /outgoing/configuration-1.zip"
```

But when i try and wildcard the file with the below

```
curl -v -u usr:"pass" ftp://11.11.11.11/outgoing/ -Q "DELE /outgoing/configuration-*.zip"
```

i ge the error below

```
errorconfiguration-*: No such file or directory
 QUOT command failed with 550
```

Can i use wildcards in curl delete?

Thanks

Comment: There are no wildcards in FTP. Any wildcard support must be done in the client, i.e. the client that wants to support wildcards should obtain a directory listing, select matching names, and perform commands on each name separately. Curl doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl does not support wildcards in any commands on an FTP server. In order to perform the required delete, you'll have to first list the files in the directory on the server, filter down to the files you want, and then issue delete commands for those.

Assuming your files are in the path `ftp://11.11.11.11/outgoing`, you could do something like:

```
curl -u usr:"pass" -l ftp://11.11.11.11/outgoing \
| grep '^configuration[-][[:digit:]]\+[.]zip$' \
| xargs -I{} -- curl -v -u usr:"pass" ftp://11.11.11.11/outgoing -Q "DELE {}"
```

That command (untested, since I don't have access to your server) does the following:

1. Outputs a directory listing for the `outgoing/outgoing` directory on the server.
2. Filters that directory listing for file names that start with `configuration-`, then have one or more digits, and then end with `.zip`. You may need to adjust this regex for different patterns.
3. Supplies the matching names to `xargs`, which, using the delimiter `{}` to interpolate each matched name, runs the `curl` command to `DELETE` each file on the server.

You could use one `curl` command to delete all of the files by concatting the matched names together into a single delete command, but that would be less legible for use as an example.

Comment: This looks great i just have to figure out the regex for the actual name of my file e.g. test-test-test-test-7.17.1-1.117.zip (its the numbers that will differ in each file

Comment: Good luck! Don't hesitate to throw grep into "PCRE" mode (much more flexible than the BRE mode I used in my example) with the `-P` switch, if your grep supports it, or just use perl regex directly with `ack` or `perl`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794145

Comment: ...and if you don't care about the numeric content (e.g. any `test-11.22.-333.44-4..5--5.6.-.-10.zip`-type string), you could use a pattern like `^test[[:digit:].-]zip$`, though that might be a bit promiscuous if you really need robustness.

Comment: This is not true. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WILDCARDMATCH.html