# Filtering a list of files with a perl one-liner

Tags: perl, grep

I'm trying to filter at the command line using grep's `-P` option, which is supposed to be using perl's regex

`ls | grep -P ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz` works

but

```
ls | grep -P ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz$
```

does not work.  It appears that anchors don't work with `grep -P` for GNU grep 3.4.

These examples are trivial, of course.

I've also tried filtering with one-liners, a la [perl one-liner like grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794145/perl-one-liner-like-grep)

```
ls | perl -ne 'print $1 if not $_ =~ m/\.gz$/'
```

but that didn't work either.

```
ls | perl -ne 'print $1 if not /\.gz$/'
```

my guess is that the best bet is the perl one-liner.

How can I re-write the above one-liner to grep on a list of files?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know, is a CRLF within a filename?

`ls | perl -ne 'print $_ if not /\.gz$/'` also fails

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `dos2unix` prints out `dos2unix: Binary symbol 0x1F found at line 1
dos2unix: Skipping binary file ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz` so my guess is yes, this is working as expected. I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew shouldn't perl be interpreting the filename as a string?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I got confused here. I do not see why you should see this issue now.

Comment: You don't need grep ([or ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)) for simple filename matching, just shell globbing... `printf "%s\n" *ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz`. For everything but a given extension, in bash (with `shopt extglob` in effect) or ksh93, or zsh (with `setopt ksh_glob`) `!(*.gz)` or in zsh with `setopt extended_glob`, `^(*.gz)`

Comment: Re "*which is supposed to be using perl's regex*", No, it's supposed to use PCRE

Comment: I don't know the solution here, but I can suggest things you could try: `ls -1` or `ls -1b` instead of just `ls` ? And perhaps quoting: `ls -1b | grep -P 'ZZZZZTYT\.vcf\.gz$'` And for your perl onliners, try `-nle` not just `-ne`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite some issues in your examples, I couldn't reproduce your problem.

For command `ls | grep -P ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz` works and `ls | grep -P ZZZZZTYT.vcf.gz$` don't, my first guess it's you have whitespaces or other "invisible" characters at the end your file. You can try `ls | cat -A` (or `cat -veT`) to see if in fact there more than you can see. Anyway your regex can be better written with literal dots (`\.`), as `.` alone matches anything.

In your perl onliners, you are trying to print `$1` and this variable is empty, from the [`perldoc perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$%3Cdigits%3E-($1,-$2,-...)):

```
$<digits> ($1, $2, ...)
     Contains the subpattern from the corresponding set of capturing
     parentheses from the last successful pattern match, not counting
     patterns matched in nested blocks that have been exited already.

     These variables are read-only and dynamically-scoped.

     Mnemonic: like \digits.
```

I think you want print `$_`, this variable holds the content of current line when you use `-n` switch (references in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$_) and perlfunc). Than you could rewrite your perl oneliner as:

```
ls | perl -ne'/\.gz$/ or print' # for not .gz files
```

or

```
ls | perl -ne'/\.gz$/ and print' # list .gz files
```

Using your examples, it is enough to remove the `$1` from the online.

As already pointed you need to check if there is something at the end of your filenames.

If there "bad characters" at the and of your filenames, this oneliner will work for listing .gz files:

```
ls | perl -ne'/\.gz.*$/ and print'
```

Comment: indeed, this works with `.pl$` but not with `.gz$`