# Perl: Getting lines from file based on user input

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I implement Unix grep in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848360/how-can-i-implement-unix-grep-in-perl)

Is there anyway I can write a perl script to print out all lines in a file that contains the string input by the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848360/how-can-i-implement-unix-grep-in-perl

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate concepts in this answer:

1. File IO, and iterating through all lines in a while
2. Regular expression, and especially passing a variable to a regular expression.

Note the use of quotemeta. It is important when the user input contains RE specific characters (which may even create an illigel RE if you don't handle it).

Here is the code:

```
print "Looking for: ";
my $input = <>;
chomp $input;
my $re = quotemeta $input;

open my $fh, "<", "myfile.txt" or die $!;
while( <$fh> ) {
    print if /$re/;
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the regular expression modifer "i"

```
print "Name: ";
my $string = <>;

open FILE, "test.txt" or die $!;

while(<FILE>) {
    chomp;
     print "$_\n" if(/$string*/i);
}
close FILE;
```

Comment: uses TYPEGLOB Filehandle not lexical

Answer (score 0):

Oh, figured out how to do it. Turned out to be quite simple
But how do I do it if I don't want the search to be case sensitive?

```
print "Name: ";
my $string = <>;

open FILE, "test.txt" or die $!;

while(<FILE>) {
    chomp;
     print "$_\n" if(/$string*/);
}
close FILE;
```

Comment: You should add an `i` to the pattern match operator: `/$string*/i`.

Comment: you also probably want to `chomp $string`

Comment: If you want to make the program more concise, replace the loop with: `print grep { /$string/i } <DATA>`. Refer: [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: and you don't want the `*` since it means zero or more times, so it will print if it matches or not

Comment: don't use TYPEGLOB Filehandle, use lexical

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN{$pattern=shift};say if /$pattern/i' pattern filename(s)
```

or

```
perl -nE 'BEGIN{$pattern=shift};say "$ARGV $.: $_" if /$pattern/i' pattern filename(s)
```

to get the file and line number too.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop body is a bit complex. This also works:

```
while (<FILE>) { print if /$string/i }
```

There's no need to chomp the newline and then add it back in.

Comment: should be a comment? also uses TYPEGLOB Filehandle not lexical