# Search array of strings for specific words

Tags: perl

Firstly, I don't know Perl at all, and need a reasonably quick answer on this.  I have the result of running a command stored in an array:

```
my @result = `$command`;
```

What I need to do is search the array to see if any element contains the word "Merge" or the word "changed" (both case insensitive).

Can someone advise please?

Comment: This is coverd by grep in perl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848360/how-can-i-implement-unix-grep-in-perl

Comment: Great, downvoted for either not knowing perl (which I openly admit) or performing inadequate Google searches.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for the job here is `grep` - a function that allows you to specify a filter against a list.  You can use it much like Unix `grep`, but it'll also allow for more complex tests (e.g. code to run).

In your case:

```
my @matches = grep { /merge|changed/i } @result; 

if ( @matches ) { 
    print "One or more lines matched\n";
}
```

Comment: You'll want `/i` on the match operator for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: `/\b(?:merge|changed)\b/i` will prevent `submerged` from matching

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression. In this example if the line match 'merge' or 'changed' (insensitive of course) the line is printed :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @result = `command`;

foreach my $line (@result){
    if ($line =~ /merge|changed/i){
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: `/\b(?:merge|changed)\b/i` will prevent `submerged` from matching

Comment: The slash in the middle -> sure it was a mistake ;)

i've tried with the command 'ps aux' and the regex /bAsh|apAChe/i
And it work great